# Dropdown state in React-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Iam trying to create a dropdown component and would like to use that selected option through out my app.
The thought is when a user select a Dropdown value then, its state got save in Redux reducer then to use that value for other action. But being a beginner Iam stuck on implementation part.

**Note:** The dropdown wouldnt have a submit button, just the action of selecting the drop down option.

My code until this stage looks like this:

RoleDropdown.js

```
class RoleDropdown extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        };
    }

    ...
    ...

    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                <select 
                  onChange={() => this.props.selectedRoleAction()}
                   name="roles" className="form-control">
                      <option>Select a Role</option>
                      <option value="ABC" >ABC</option>
                      <option value="DEF" >DEF</option>
                      <option value="GHI" >GHI</option>

                </select>
                <p>role is: {this.props.activeRole.value}</p>   //No value output here
                </div>
        )
    }
```

SelectedRoleAction.js

```
  const selectedRoleAction = (role) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("")
    setValue({ value: role.target.value })
    console.log("event from drop down is " + role)  //I cant see any logged value as well
    return {
        type: "ROLE_SELECTED",
        payload: role,
    }
};
```

Where Am I doing wrong? Does the "setValue" can be used in action reducers?

Comment: `useState` is a function that is used to hold local state. It has nothing to do with redux. There are a lot of issues with your code right now. I highly recommend you check out a youtube tutorial on how to use redux.

Answer (score 1):

An action creator does not hold any local state.  It is just a function that maps from some arguments to a Redux action which is an object with properties `type` and `payload`.

This is an action creator function:

```
const selectedRoleAction = (role) => {
    return {
        type: "ROLE_SELECTED",
        payload: role,
    }
};
```

In which case your component would call:

```
onChange={(e) => this.props.selectedRoleAction(e.target.value)}
```

You are trying to map from the event to the value in the action creator rather than in the component.  This is unusual and I would recommend the above approach, but it's doable.

```
const selectedRoleEventHandler = (event) => {
    return {
        type: "ROLE_SELECTED",
        payload: event.target.value,
    }
};
```

In which case your component would call:

```
onChange={(e) => this.props.selectedRoleEventHandler(e)}
```

or just:

```
onChange={this.props.selectedRoleEventHandler}
```

Right now you are calling the function with no arguments `this.props.selectedRoleAction()` which will not work.

---

That just creates the action.  I'm assuming that you are using the `connect` higher-order component so that calling `this.props.selectedRoleAction` will dispatch it to Redux.

The actual state is set through your Redux reducer function.

---

If the value is stored and updated through Redux then it should not also be in the component state.

You are dealing with a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) so you'll want to set the `value` property on your `select`.

I am disabling "Select a Role" and also giving it a value of the empty string `""`.  I am using that value as a fallback if `this.props.activeRole` is not set.

```
<select
   name="roles"
   className="form-control"
   value={this.props.selectedRole || ""}
   onChange={(e) => this.props.selectedRoleAction(e.target.value)}
>
    <option value="" disabled>Select a Role</option>
    <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
    <option value="GHI">GHI</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Linda,Yes Iam using connect here. This helps a lot really. Thanks for the guidance.